# Mobile native app: long-running background task (with Ruby)?

Tags: android, ruby, mobile, thermal-printer, network-printers

I'm very newbie in mobile apps developement.
I would like to implement the client-server architecture designed here attached.

[image]

Let say I have:

1. Server Side: a "standard" e-commerce web application containing also a sort of API
   server that may be polled by a remote client to ask "new Orders".
2. Client side, a mobile phone app containing a long-running background task that realize this pseudocode (Ruby):

[image: ruby code]

So the script poll the server every N second, with a HTPPS GET to fetch new Orders and in case print orders to a local thermal printer (ESC/POS) 
BTW, a secondary problem I have is to understand the communication media to connect printer to snmartphone (USB, or WI-FI, (or Bluethoot...). In my mobile device ignorance, I'm assume that I "simply" have to write bytecodes to a "serial line"...

Questions:
Do you think feasible to run this kind of "just-background" long-running script on a smartphone (like and Android 4.x device) ?

Because I'm a Ruby developer (server-side), It would be great to possibly use Ruby as developement language also in the handset device; possible ?

BTW, I'm just start reading [Rhodes](http://www.motorolasolutions.com/XU-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Software+and+Applications/RhoMobile_Suite?WT.mc_id=RhoMobile%20Suite%22?) that seem very promisimg multiplatform (Android, iOS, Windows) SDK. 
Any experience with that framework? 
Any suggested alternative ?

Or I have to code my app using 
- flat native Java (Android), Objective-c (IOS), and oso on ?

Thanks for your help!
giorgio

Comment: Why not use some sort of push, in stead of pulling every x seaconds? Also: I think you will have a very hard time using a printer from a mobile phone. There is, as far as I know, no native support for ruby on mobile devices. You would have to use some sort of wrapper like Titanium or, as you mention, Rhodes. Is it essential that you support all platforms? In that case I think you have quite the challenge on your hand by supporting printing. That would be a full blown app in itself which you could monetize.

Comment: yes push would be better! but I have no clear ideas about a suitable protocol. flat poll is awful but need just a flat HTTP GET. Printers from a smartphone ? A nightmare as far as I see.. About platforms: basically I'd happy starting with Android.So probably I'll risign myself to java... :-)

Comment: Google has some nice apis for message pushing. It might be for android only, I cant really remember. Might also be third party services for this.